# Как сервер идентифицирует пользователя с помощью session_id?

Tags: сервер, http

Мне не совсем понятно как это происходит. К примеру:

1. Пользователь заходит на сайт - отправляет запрос. Сервер отправляет ответ вместе с уникальным `session_id`.
2. Пользователь проходит авторизацию - вводит логин и пароль.
3. Пользователь зашел в свой аккаунт. Там он отправляет разные запросы к серверу.

Как сервер понимает, что все запросы от одного клиента? Условно говоря, сервер записывает себе в каком-то временном хранилище (оно действует только на время сессии), что такой-то `session_id` это такой-то `user_id`? Используется ли ip адрес для идентификации пользователя?

Comment: session_id — это просто набор буковок, а дальше сервер делает с этими буковками что хочет: например, записывает в базе таблицу соответствия между session_id и user_id. Используется ли IP-адрес — опять же зависит от хотелок конкретного сервера (но вроде обычно не используется)

Answer (score 0):

Реализовать можно как угодно. В том числе и по ip.
Но конкретно сессии, пишутся в куки.
И когда браузер отправляет запрос на сервер, он в числе прочих данных передаёт данные куки, где записан `session_id`.
Это можно посмотреть, открыв инструменты разработчика, вкладка `network`. Нажать F12 в браузере. Там видно какие данные улетают на сервер